Multihop shared SSH tunnel
I would like to create a multihop SSH tunnel that allows multiple SSH sessions for users but only uses one SSH session on the Second Hop.
Scenario:
User 1 --\
         |
User 2   ---> First Hop ---> Second Hop ---> Svr
         |
User 3 --/

First Hop is a shared user that everyone uses (call it user1)
Second Hop is also a shared user (call it user2)
Svr uses the arguments provided
The way I have it set up currently is:

An end user will do "ssh user1@FirstHop  "
user1's login shell on First Hop is an expect script
expect script does "ssh user2@SecondHop" and gets the login prompt from Svr
expect script sends Svr user/Svr pass and logs in to Svr
end user is logged in to Svr

My problem is that the Second Hop server has a 10 ssh session limit per user, and since it's a shared user and there are way more than 10 users trying to login to Svr, I often get "Too many logins for user".
I have root access to the First Hop, but not the Second Hop.
Is there a way to provide the same functionality but only using ONE ssh session on the Second Hop?
I tried the regular ssh -L :localhost: tunneling method, but i don't think that will work. It sounds like SOCKS proxy is the way to go, but I cannot get it to work.

Do the users know the user/pwd of SecondHop and server? Can you use private/publickeys for the server?

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [su], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

jeb was very helpful and solved my problem. I can delete it but what harm in keeping it since there is a solution.

It could be done with one LocalForward from FirstHop to SecondHop.
This should only be started once in a tmux/screen/nohup session.
FirstHop$ ssh userSecondHop@secondHop -L 2022:<EndServer>:22

A user can connect to the EndServer by
ssh EndUser@localhost -p 2022 -J defaultUser@firsthop

Btw. If you can't switch to private/public keys, would recommend to use the SSH-variables instead of expect scripts.
SSH_ASKPASS=myScript.sh
SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=prefer

